# Json with pagination - run in one go

Tags: php, json

The json format is like this (all data) + pagination key at the bottom.

I have to insert every single data in SQL from that json, the problem is that I can't figure it out how to go from page 1 to 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 etc with PHP in one go.

The page key isn't something logical, just a random base64 encrypted string.

The url is in this format: https://example.com/json?order=asc&key=GeneratedKeyFromPrevJson.

Anyone has any ideea how I can parse the whole thing in one go? I just can't figure it out.

All I'm thinking is to just query it with ajax and create next button that inserts the data and just do it manually. But it has at least 30~k pages.

Sorry if I seem dummb but I don't have much experience.

Comment: Is this data public? Can you share the link to (one of the) the 30~k pages ?

Comment: Hi Daniel, please share some bite of your code, will be better.

Comment: Data is not public, I'm really sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not provided much details, am assuming things here.

Here's the idea:

First fetch the API (the URL from which you are receiving the JSON data). Then from the response received, use the `key` returned for pagination. And fetch the API again, passing this `key`.

You need to iterate this using a loop. And the condition you can use would be something like checking whether the data (the actual records) returned is empty or not. If empty, exit the loop. Otherwise continue the loop.
If there's any other field that returns something related to the next page data (say whether there's new page or not), you can use that in your condition.

You can use [cURL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples.php) to call the API and fetch the data. Which I assume you have already coded.

Another important thing is, if you are unsure how many pages in total it would be, you would probably need to increase your script's maximum execution time to a higher value. Because the default value would be 30 seconds. And in your case, your code will stop executing unless you increase the maximum execution time using the [set_time_limit()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) function. Call this function passing a higher value at the very top of the code.

*Here's the steps:*

1. set_time_limit to a higher value
2. fetch the data from the API using cURL
3. check whether there's data or next page's `key` or use any other condition here
4. insert the data to your database
5. if the condition in **#3** succeeds, goto **#2** and fetch the data using the `key` received
6. if the condition in **#3** fails, exit

Hope you got the idea.